# Flatlist array error in react native

Tags: arrays, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I know this might be a stupid ass question, but I have been trying to get this working for weeks.

I am trying to query data from my Firebase Cloud Firestore, and it works in the console with the following:

```
firestore.collection("tips").onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {

    const pusher = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {

        pusher.push({
          tips: doc.data().tips,
          user: doc.data().user,
          date: doc.data().date,
        });
    });
    console.log(pusher);
    });
```

[image]

But then I try to output it to a Flatlist:

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = ({
      pusher: [],
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <Flatlist
          data={this.state.pusher}
          renderItem={({ item, index}) => {
            return (
              <Text>{item.tips}</Text>
            )
          }}
        >
        </Flatlist>
    )
}
```

I get this error:

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
>   the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named
>   imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Home`.
>
> This error is located at:
>       in RCTScrollContentView (at ScrollView.js:955)
>       in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:1070)
>       in ScrollView (at KeyboardAwareHOC.js:397)
>       in _class (at Content.js:125)
>       in Content (at connectStyle.js:384)
>       in Styled(Content) (at Home.js:86)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:43)
>       in Container (at connectStyle.js:384)
>       in Styled(Container) (at Home.js:85)
>       in Home (at SceneView.js:9)
>       in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.js:574)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:43)
>       in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewCard.js:12)
>       in Card (at createPointerEventsContainer.js:28)
>       in Container (at StackViewLayout.js:612)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:43)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:43)
>       in StackViewLayout (at withOrientation.js:30)
>       in withOrientation (at StackView.js:63)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:43)
>       in Transitioner (at StackView.js:21)
>       in StackView (at createNavigator.js:59)
>       in Navigator (at createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js:11)
>       in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at createNavigationContainer.js:376)
>       in NavigationContainer (at renderApplication.js:32)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:43)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:43)
>       in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:31)
>
> getFiberTagFromObjectType
>       7a29fe2c-d11b-4ce4-b2b9-0f3bcbe09827:19412:15 createFiberFromElement
>       7a29fe2c-d11b-4ce4-b2b9-0f3bcbe09827:19370:26 createChild
>       7a29fe2c-d11b-4ce4-b2b9-0f3bcbe09827:21491:34 reconcileChildrenArray
>       7a29fe2c-d11b-4ce4-b2b9-0f3bcbe09827:21720:31 reconcileChildFibers
>       7a29fe2c-d11b-4ce4-b2b9-0f3bcbe09827:22006:20 reconcileChildrenAtExpirationTime
>       7a29fe2c-d11b-4ce4-b2b9-0f3bcbe09827:22353:34 reconcileChildren
>       7a29fe2c-d11b-4ce4-b2b9-0f3bcbe09827:22348:9 updateHostComponent
>       7a29fe2c-d11b-4ce4-b2b9-0f3bcbe09827:22618:9 beginWork
>       7a29fe2c-d11b-4ce4-b2b9-0f3bcbe09827:23027:20

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16332)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using wrong react native component.

Use **FlatList** instead of **Flatlist**.